# Change Spyder and Matplotlib figure size for saved plots only

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I would like to view matplotlib plots inside Spyders IPython console in one size and save figures to a multipage PDF in a different size.

Currently I set the figure size as follows:

```
plt.rc('axes', grid=True)
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(12, 8))
plt.rc('legend', fancybox=True, framealpha=1)
```

Then I plot some figures and save them to a list for saving a PDF later on. This works just fine when used alone. The plots are approriately sized for viewing in Spyder IPython console.

At the end of my script I have a loop to go through each of the figures I want to save. In here I want to set the layout and figure size exactly for better printing on an A3 paper.

```
with PdfPages('multi.pdf') as pdf:
    for fig in figs:
        fig.tight_layout()
        fig.set_size_inches(420/25.4, 297/25.4)
        pdf.savefig(figure=fig)
```

The output PDF is just like I want it to be, but the problem is with the plots shown inside Spyder. Changing the figure size while saving also affects the plots viewed inside Spyder. And using the size of an A3  makes the plots way too big.

So the question is: How do I change the size of saved PDF figures without changing the size of figures shown inside Spyder?

Comment: I tried using `copy.deepcopy(fig)` on my figure to make a separate copy. This didn't work either.

Comment: What about changing the figure size back after saving?

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the simple solution is too hard to figure out without someone pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing out the solution.

I went with a solution that allows me to set `plt.rc` in the beginning to my taste and then revert to the set values after exporting the figures to a PDF.

First I set the values I use:

```
plt.rc('axes', grid=True)
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(12, 8))
plt.rc('legend', fancybox=True, framealpha=1)
```

With these I can plot what I need with just the default values. Then I create the PDF with:

```
with PdfPages('multi.pdf') as pdf:
    for fig in figs:
        fig.set_size_inches(420/25.4, 297/25.4)
        pdf.savefig(figure=fig, bbox_inches='tight')
        fig.set_size_inches(plt.rcParams.get('figure.figsize'))
```

With this I can get the `fig.tight_layout()` only on the exported figure and restore the figure size to the default value set earlier.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, changing the figure size back after saving should work and may probably solved you problem.

But, depending on your specific problem, it is possible that you are going to face scaling issues since the size of the figures saved in the pdf is much bigger than the size of those displayed in the IPython console. If you scale everything to look great on the pdf, then it is possible that everything is going to look too big in IPython as shown in the example below:

[image]

If you don't need the plot to be interactive in IPython, a solution may be to generate your figures to look good for the pdf and display a scaled bitmap version of them in the IPython console as shown in the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Image, display
try:  # Python 2
    from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    from io import BytesIO

# Generate a matplotlib figures that looks good on A3 format :

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(150), np.random.rand(150), 'o', color='0.35', ms=25,
        alpha=0.85)

ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=46, labelpad=25)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=46, labelpad=25)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=30, pad=15,
               direction='out', top=False, right=False, width=3, length=10)
for loc in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[loc].set_linewidth(3)

# Save figure to pdf in A3 format:

w, h = 420/25.4, 297/25.4
with PdfPages('multi.pdf') as pdf:
    fig.set_size_inches(w, h)
    fig.tight_layout()
    pdf.savefig(figure=fig)
    plt.close(fig)

# Display in Ipython a sclaled bitmap using a buffer to save the png :

buf = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=90)
display(Image(data=buf.getvalue(), format='png', width=450, height=450*h/w,
              unconfined=True))
```

which shows in the IPython console as:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This does what I asked for in the original question but the solution is in my opinion too complex for the task. This requires you to manually adjust quite a lot of figure settings first. That is why I posted a solution which I went with.

Comment: @saikon you are quite welcomed. Of course the solution above is overkill for probably most cases. Note however that the manual adjustments to the figure are by no means required and the solution would also work with the default values. It was only to show that scaling of the text, markers and line size could be an issue in some instances when scaling a matplotlib figure from one size to another.